# Cannot connect MySQL to Clickhouse using DBeaver

Tags: mysql, clickhouse, dbeaver

I try to connect MySQL to Clickhouse using DBeaver (MySQL Driver, connector version 8.0.29)without success. The log recorded the following error:

```
2023.03.23 16:27:55.522982 [ 4356 ] {} <Error> MySQLHandler: MySQLHandler: Cannot read packet: : Code: 60. DB::Exception: Table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEYWORDS doesn't exist. (UNKNOWN_TABLE), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. ./build_docker/../src/Common/Exception.cpp:91: DB::Exception::Exception(DB::Exception::MessageMasked&&, int, bool) @ 0xe12b715 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>(int, FormatStringHelperImpl<std::__1::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>::type>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>&&) @ 0x8999504 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. ./build_docker/../src/Interpreters/DatabaseCatalog.cpp:0: DB::DatabaseCatalog::getTableImpl(DB::StorageID const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, std::__1::optional<DB::Exception>*) const @ 0x12d2af9a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. ./build_docker/../contrib/llvm-project/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h:801: DB::DatabaseCatalog::getTable(DB::StorageID const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>) const @ 0x12d31c6a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. ./build_docker/../src/Interpreters/JoinedTables.cpp:0: DB::JoinedTables::getLeftTableStorage() @ 0x13807e34 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. ./build_docker/../src/Interpreters/InterpreterSelectQuery.cpp:0: DB::InterpreterSelectQuery::InterpreterSelectQuery(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context> const&, std::__1::optional<DB::Pipe>, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::PreparedSets>) @ 0x1372dcb2 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. ./build_docker/../contrib/llvm-project/libcxx/include/optional:260: DB::InterpreterSelectWithUnionQuery::buildCurrentChildInterpreter(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>> const&) @ 0x137c4822 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. ./build_docker/../src/Interpreters/InterpreterSelectWithUnionQuery.cpp:0: DB::InterpreterSelectWithUnionQuery::InterpreterSelectWithUnionQuery(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>> const&) @ 0x137c27ca in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. ./build_docker/../contrib/llvm-project/libcxx/include/vector:434: DB::InterpreterFactory::get(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST>&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, DB::SelectQueryOptions const&) @ 0x136e9750 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. ./build_docker/../src/Interpreters/executeQuery.cpp:0: DB::executeQueryImpl(char const*, char const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, bool, DB::QueryProcessingStage::Enum, DB::ReadBuffer*) @ 0x13ae5460 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ./build_docker/../contrib/llvm-project/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h:612: DB::executeQuery(DB::ReadBuffer&, DB::WriteBuffer&, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, std::__1::function<void (DB::QueryResultDetails const&)>, std::__1::optional<DB::FormatSettings> const&) @ 0x13aeb6e9 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ./build_docker/../contrib/llvm-project/libcxx/include/optional:260: DB::MySQLHandler::comQuery(DB::ReadBuffer&) @ 0x14867573 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ./build_docker/../src/Server/MySQLHandler.cpp:175: DB::MySQLHandler::run() @ 0x14863fee in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. ./build_docker/../base/poco/Net/src/TCPServerConnection.cpp:57: Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection::start() @ 0x177a6634 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. ./build_docker/../contrib/llvm-project/libcxx/include/__memory/unique_ptr.h:48: Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::run() @ 0x177a785b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. ./build_docker/../base/poco/Foundation/src/ThreadPool.cpp:202: Poco::PooledThread::run() @ 0x1792f0a7 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
16. ./build_docker/../base/poco/Foundation/include/Poco/SharedPtr.h:231: Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) @ 0x1792cadd in /usr/bin/clickhouse
17. ? @ 0x7f8bb062c802 in ?
18. ? @ 0x7f8bb05cc450 in ?
 (version 23.3.1.755 (official build))
```

but I succeeded by using command line from Powershell

```
 mysql -h **.***.**.*** -P 9004 -u admin --password=******

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 74
Server version: 23.3.1.755-ClickHouse

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

How can I do it using DBeaver? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL wire protocol usage isn't a strict requirement, you could try to follow the official tutorial: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/dbeaver

Comment: MySQL wire protocol is incomplete in Clickhouse. Mysql JDBC driver is unable to use Clickhouse.